# calling jquery function from a link after adding link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to call a jquery function after I add it using jquery. Here is my code (this is already in document.ready):

```
  $("#addrow").on("click",function() {
    alert("made it");
    //$('#moduletable tr:last').after('<tr class="child"'+table_length+'><td>info</td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    table_length += 1;

  });

  $("input[name='module_type']").change(function(){
    var content = "";

    //content += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addrow">Add row</a>';
    content += '<br><br>';
    content += '<table id="moduletable" style="width:100%">';
    content += '<tbody>';
    content += '<tr>';
    content += '<td align="center">Question</td><td align="center">Header</td><td align="center">Content</td>';
    content += '</tr>';
    content += '</tbody>';
    content += '</table>';

    $("#content").html(content);


  });
```

The problem is with

```
    content += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addrow">Add row</a>';
```

If I write it into the html page when it loads the function gets called. If I add this link after the page loads, it doesn't.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','#addrow',your_callback)`

Comment: That is jquery default behaviour, it does not register event handlers for elements inserted in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but I believe that you're not assigning the function to any elements.

From the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object

When you call `$("#addrow").on( ... )` there are no elements matching the query `#addrow`, meaning that the "currently selected set of elements" is empty, i.e. `$("#addrow").length == 0`

The solution is either to set the event after the element is created or to assign an event to a parent that fires only when the specified elements are targeted. As you are creating the elements through html the prior is not applicable.

The latter would be (as mentioned by [user1663189](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464978/calling-jquery-function-from-a-link-after-adding-link-using-jquery/33465174#33465174)) to use [`.delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead, wich will "Attach a handler to [...] elements that match the selector, now or in the future". [Rayon Dabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464978/calling-jquery-function-from-a-link-after-adding-link-using-jquery/33465174#comment54715584_33464978) also pointed out that you can use the optional parameter `.on(event [, selector])`and assign the listener to a parent element to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

The right way to do this is:
$( document ).delegate( "#addrow", "click", callback);